# Magento 2.4.4, Product count in layered navigation is incorrect after setting "Display Out of Stock Products" to "Yes"

Tags: indexing, magento2, magento2.4.4

Magento 2.4.4, Product count in layered navigation is incorrect after setting "Display Out of Stock Products"  to "Yes". (**STORES->Configuration->CATALOG->Inventory->Display Out of Stock Products**)

Any idea why this hapening ?

Should show correct product count in layered navigation after setting "Display Out of Stock Products"  to "Yes"